# Create dynamic javascript Object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using `Fabric.js`. For images, I want to provide `image filter` options to the users.

The below is the code for creating **new Gayscale Filter**:

```
    var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale();
    canvas.getActiveObject().filters=[];
    canvas.getActiveObject().applyFilters(_canvasObject.renderAll.bind(_canvasObject));
  canvas.getActiveObject().filters.push(filter);
    canvas.getActiveObject().applyFilters(_canvasObject.renderAll.bind(_canvasObject));
```

For other filters also the code is almost same which is repetitive except for the first line.

I provide checkboxes for the users to select the Filter. I am looping through all the `checkBoxes` and adding `event listener` to apply new filter. So in the below code I want to dynamically create filter Object.

```
var filterClickHandler = function(selectedFilter){
    return function(){
        applySelectedFilter(selectedFilter);
    }
}

function applySelectedFilter(selectedFilter){
//selectedFilter may be Grayscale,Sepia,etc...
// var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale();
 var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.selectedFilter();
}
```

Anyway to do so?

Comment: Can you please provide fiddle for it??

Answer (score 0):

fabricJS classes are still plain objects.
You can do something as simply as:

```
function applySelectedFilter(selectedFilter){
 var filter = new fabric.Image.filters[selectedFilter]();
}
```